# Calculate covered query term number divided by the number of query terms in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to calculate covered query term number divided by the number of query term. For calculating covered query term number, I can use `termfreq()` functionQuery. But how can I calculate number of query term ? Is there any function for that ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'number of query term'? Provide examples and expectations.

Comment: sumTotalTermFreq may help but then again I can only guess what you are looking for with limited explanation in the question.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/function-queries.html#sumtotaltermfreq-function